# How to show nearby places in google map android

Tags: java, android

I am currently making an app which uses google map on android using java. I want to fetch user current location and then show nearby hospitals. I have integrate the map in android and also fetch the current location but I don't know how to show nearby places so please help me. I am newbie to android and also stack overflow.

Comment: Take a look on the Places API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search

Comment: @AlexanderZhukov Is the API paid and can you explain how to do it in android using java?